# Join over RDDs in pyspark with over common column

Tags: pyspark, rdd, self-join

My RDD looks like this:

`myrdd = sc.parallelize([('a','b'),('a','c'),('b','c'),('c','d')])`

I want to print rows from my RDD where the second element of a row and the first element of any other row are common. So, I want to do self-join.

The result I want is:

`a,b,c` because `a,b` and `b,c` are both present in my RDD.

I am using the `join` function

`result = myrdd.join(myrdd)`

but it gives me

```
[('b', ('c', 'c')),
 ('c', ('d', 'd')),
 ('a', ('b', 'b')),
 ('a', ('b', 'c')),
 ('a', ('c', 'b')),
 ('a', ('c', 'c'))]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Edit: Desired output: `(a,b,c)` or `(a,c,b)` (but not both)

Comment: [('a','b'),('a','c'),('b','c'),('c','d')] join [('a','b'),('a','c'),('b','c'),('c','d')], so from left hand side, it matches 'a' to corresponding values on right side which are 'b' and 'c'. Hence it is returning (a , ('b','c')), (a,('b','b')), (a,('c','b')), (a,('c','c')). Now let's look at one record (a, ('b','c')), here a is the key, 'b' is the value of the key from left RDD and 'c' is the value of key 'a' from the right RDD. Everything is correct. Your expected result (a,('b','c')) is also there in the result.

Comment: I do not want the other rows in the results RDD such as b,(c,c) or a,(c,c). How can I remove those?

Comment: Are you looking for `result = myrdd.join(myrdd.map(lambda x: (x[1],))`? Post the desired output.

Comment: @pault Updated!

Answer (score 1):

You can use a filter on the result to exclude the results where two values of a key are not the same.

```
myrdd = sc.parallelize([('a','b'),('a','c'),('b','c'),('c','d')])

result = myrdd.join(myrdd)

#Output 

[('a', ('b', 'b')), ('a', ('b', 'c')), ('a', ('c', 'b')), ('a', ('c', 'c')), ('b', ('c', 'c')), ('c', ('d', 'd'))]

a = result.filter(lambda x:x[1][0] !=x[1][1])

#Output 

[('a', ('b', 'c')), ('a', ('c', 'b'))]
```

You can also combine both the operations:

```
myrdd.join(myrdd).filter(lambda x:x[1][0] !=x[1][1]).collect()
```

Comment: Is there any way to remove duplicates like (a,(b,c)) and (a,(c,b))?